# Displaying dynamic content in magnific popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, magnific-popup

I am trying to do a dynamic content magnific popup.

This is my current code.

```php
if ($queryResult > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<div class='hvrbox'>
     <img src='image/".$row['mImage']."' alt='' class='hvrbox-layer_bottom' />
     <div class='hvrbox-layer_top'>
       <a href='#posterVid1' class='posterbtn1' id='posterLink1'>Play Trailer</a>
       <div id='posterVid1' class='mfp-hide' style='max-width: 75%; margin: 0 auto;'>
           <iframe width='853' height='480' src='".$row['mLink']."' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>
       </div>
       <a class='posterbtn2' href='movie-detail.php?name=".$row['mName']."'>Movie Details</a>
       <div class='hvrbox-text'>Me Before You</div>
     </div>
   </div>";
      }
    }
```

This is the javascript

```js
$('#posterLink1, #posterLink2, #posterLink3')
.magnificPopup({
      type:'inline',
      midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
  })
```

Since the magnific popup I'm using only opens content based on the `id` given in the `id` tag and in the JavaScript, if I have different content, the `id` still stays the same and the button only opens the same content over and over again because the `id` is the same.  Because the content I'm getting is from a database, I can't replicate the code over and over again and only change the `id` like in a static page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have a counter in your loop. Also you don't need the `id` for calling the `magnificPopup`, instead use `class` for dynamic.

**PHP:**

```
if ($queryResult > 0) {
    $ctr = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<div class='hvrbox'>
            <img src='image/".$row['mImage']."' alt='' class='hvrbox-layer_bottom' />
            <div class='hvrbox-layer_top'>
                <a href='#posterVid".$ctr."' class='posterbtn1'>Play Trailer</a>
                <div id='posterVid".$ctr."' class='mfp-hide' style='max-width: 75%; margin: 0 auto;'>
                    <iframe width='853' height='480' src='".$row['mLink']."' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <a class='posterbtn2' href='movie-detail.php?name=".$row['mName']."'>Movie Details</a>
                <div class='hvrbox-text'>Me Before You</div>
            </div>
        </div>";
        $ctr++;
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.posterbtn1')
    .magnificPopup({
        type:'inline',
        midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
    })
```

Comment: No problem, glad I can help.